# Upper bound for the size of a $k$-uniform $s$-wise $t$-intersecting set system

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-set-theory

Given integers $n \geq k \geq t \geq 1$ and an integer $s$, let $m(n,k,s,t)$ denote the maximum size of a family $\mathcal F$ of $k$-subsets of $[n]$, i.e. $\mathcal F \subseteq \binom{[n]}{k}$, such that the intersection of any $s$ members of $\mathcal F$ is at least $t$.

**My question is**: what is the best known upper bound on $m(n,k,s,t)$?

Below are what I was able to dig out from the literature.

The classic Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem ([EKR 61] plus a result by [Wilson 1984]) states that $m(n,k,2,t) \leq \binom{n-t}{k-t}$ for $n \geq n_0(k,t) = (k-t+1)(t+1)$. This bound is tight for $n \geq n_0$.

[Ahlswede and Khachatrian 1997] derived tight bounds for the $n &lt; n_0$ case, completely settling the pairwise $t$-intersecting sub-problem.

[Frankl 1974] showed that $m(n,k,s,1) \leq \binom{n-1}{k-1}$, provided that $ks \leq n(s-1)$. This bound is tight. (When $ks > n(s-1)$, the intersection of any $s$ members of $\mathcal F$ is not empty.) Several other papers of Frankl gave some bounds for the non-uniform case, i.e. when members of $\mathcal F$ do not need to be of the same size $k$.

[[Tokushige 2007](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.77.2683&rep=rep1&type=pdf)] gave a bound for $m(n,k,3,t)$. Conjecture 1 in that paper specifies a formula for $m(n,k,s,t)$ but not much evidence was given other than that the conjecture holds for $s=2$. I'd be interested to know whether the conjecture holds if we replace $=$ by $\leq$.

There are also some other papers discussing bounds when $s$ and $t$ are small constants.

In summary, I was not able to find any generic upper bound for $m(n,k,s,t)$ (except for the obvious fact that $s$-wise $t$-intersecting systems are also $(s-1)$-wise $t$-intersecting systems, and thus the EKR bound applies).

Comment: I've removed the LaTeX in the title because it does not render properly on the front page or the questions page.

Comment: It might help to mention an obvious lower bound: (n-t) choose (k-t).  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.04.15

Comment: Now that the math has rendered correctly, it seems the lower bound (n-t) choose (k-t) figures often, and is applicable when s <= (n-t) choose (k-t), and may not apply otherwise.

Comment: Somewhat related is Fisher's inquality.  That is, if we insist that every two sets have intersection *exactly* $t$, then there can be at most $n$ such sets (where $n$ is the size of the underlying set).  Indeed, this holds even in the non-uniform case. 

Comment: Thanks Gerhard & Tony for the comments.

@Gerhard, I did implicitly mention the $\binom{n-t}{k-t}$ bound in the last paragraph.

@Tony, I'm aware of the Fisher's inequality. It's perhaps a little too far from what I'm seeking.

Answer (score 2):

This is not as general as what is asked, but in [N. Tokushige, *The random walk method for intersecting families,* in Horizons of Combinatorics, Bolyai Society Mathematical Studies, **17** (2008) 215-224,](http://www.cc.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/~hide/survey-balaton.pdf) it is stated that

> For any fixed $p = \frac{k}{n}$ such that $p < \frac{s-1}{s+1}$ and $n$ large enough,
>
> $$m(n,k,s,t) \leq \alpha_{s, p}^t{{n}\choose{k}},$$
>
> where $\alpha_{s,p} \in (p, 1)$ is the unique root of the equation $(1-p)x^s-x+p$.

The proof can be found in [N. Tokushige, *The maximum size of 4-wise 2-intersecting and 4-wise 2-union families*, European J. Combin., **27** (2006) 814-825,](http://www.cc.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/~hide/4iu.pdf) where this is used as a tool to prove a strong theorem for specific $t$ and $s$. Upper bounds of the same kind seem to be proved in other places as well to give strong theorems for different fixed $t$ and $s$.

The first paper I linked to also proves that

> There exist positive constants $n_1$, $\epsilon$ such that for all $t$ such that $1 \leq t \leq \frac{3^s-2s-1}{2}$ and all $n > n_1$ and $k$ such that $\frac{k}{n} < \frac{1}{3}+\epsilon$,
>
> $$m(n,k,s,t) = \max\left\{{{n-t}\choose{k-t}}, (t+s){{n-t-s}\choose{k-t-s+1}}+{{n-t-s}\choose{k-t-s}}\right\}.$$

Note that ${n-t}\choose{k-t}$ and $(t+s){{n-t-s}\choose{k-t-s+1}}+{{n-t-s}\choose{k-t-s}}$ are exactly the sizes of $\mathcal{F}_0$ and $\mathcal{F}_1$ respectively in $\text{Conjecture}\ 1$ in question. So, this proves the conjecture for a restricted case. Results in the same spirit by the same author can also be found in

[N. Tokushige, *Multiply-intersecting families revisited*, J. Combin. Theory B, **97** (2007) 929-948](http://www.cc.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/~hide/rwise-web.pdf)

and

[N. Tokushige, *A multiply intersecting Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem - The principal case*, Discrete Math. **310** (2010) 453-460](http://www.cc.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/~hide/g-final.pdf).